# Can I (install and) use guix-home on a non-Guix Linux distribution?

Tags: non-root-user, guix, home-manager

I'm interested in setting up an environment of apps, libraries and utilities for use - independently and in conjunction - by a non-root user on a GNU/Linux system. Can I use [GUIX's "home" mechanism](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/devel/en/html_node/Home-Configuration.html) for doing that, even though the OS distribution is not GUIX? Similarly to how [Nix' home-manager](https://github.com/nix-community/home-manager) is used?

Answer (score 2):

Debian has it

```
#↳ apt list guix
Listing... Done
guix/stable 1.4.0-3 amd64
```

Comment: ... and does that do what I'd like it to? i.e. allow installing and un-installing apps, libs etc. under the user's home directory?

Comment: Looks like it.  `apt show` provides the description which says: "Guix supports transactional upgrades and roll-backs, unprivileged
 package management, and more."